# AngularJS ignores inline style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following:

```
<span ng-bind-html="product.icon"></span>
```

If `product.icon` contains:

```
<img src="http://localhost/angularjs/public/gfx/product/logo_1.png" width="18" height="18">
```

It will display fine. However, if it contains:

```
<img src="http://localhost/angularjs/public/gfx/product/logo_1.png" style="width: 18px; height: 18px">
```

Then `width` and `height` are not respected.

Why this behavior? Is it because of `:` or `;` from the inline style?

Comment: what do you mean `not respected`? If inside `<span>` you can see `<img..>` then your question probably has nothing to do with angular, but rather with css

Comment: This only happens when using `ng-bind-html`.

Comment: ["By default, the resulting HTML content will be sanitized using the `$sanitize` service"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it was not enough to use `ng-bind-html`, I had to combine it with this filter:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);
```

Now using `<span ng-bind-html="product.logo_and_name | to_trusted"></span>` the inline css is respected.