# change font size for getElementsByClassName

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I scrap a paragraph in a page using getElementsByClassName. However, I unable to change the **font Size and color** of the output.

Below is my code to scrap.

```
var keyPeople1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_people module")[0].children;
for (var i = 0; i < keyPeople1.length; i++) {
  keyPeople1[i].style.fontSize = "2em";
}
$scope.keyPeople = "<div class='cr_profile_people module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+keyPeople1[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data cr_board'>"+keyPeople1[1].innerHTML+"</div></div>";
```

The for loop was suppose to change the font size but it just does not work.

html snippet

`<div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="keyPeople"></div>`

add fontsize in style `<div style="margin: 10px;font-size:60%;"ng-bind-html="keyPeople"></div>` has no effect on the font size.

Please guide the correct way to change the font size and its color.
[image]

Full code

angular js to scrap a page

```
.controller("companyOwnershipCtrl",function($scope,$http,$ionicLoading,$state,$cashDataFactory){


  $ionicLoading.show();

  $http.get("http://vinn.johnapi.com/wsjapi?url=http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/U11/company-people")
  .success(function(response){
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();

    tmp.body.innerHTML = response;

    //Company Info
    var companyInfo1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_contact")[0].children;
    var companyInfo2 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_overview_data cr_data")[0].children;

    $scope.companyInfo = "<div class='cr_profile_contact'>"+companyInfo1[0].innerHTML+"</div>";
    $scope.companyInfo += "<div class='cr_overview_data cr_data'>"+companyInfo2[0].innerHTML+"</div>";

    //Description
    var description1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_description_full cr_expand")[0].children;
    $scope.companyDescription = "<p>"+description1[0].innerHTML+"</p>";

    //Key People
    var keyPeople1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_people module")[0].children;
    $scope.keyPeople = "<div class='cr_profile_people module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+keyPeople1[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data cr_board'>"+keyPeople1[1].innerHTML+"</div></div>";

    //Average Growth Rates
    var growth = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_growth module")[0].children;
    var growth1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_insider module")[0].children;
    $scope.averageGrowthRates = "<div class='cr_profile_growth module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+growth[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+growth[1].innerHTML+"</div></div>";
    $scope.averageGrowthRates += "<div class='cr_profile_insider module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+growth1[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+growth1[1].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+growth1[2].innerHTML+"</div></div>";

    //ownership
    var ownership = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_ownership module")[0].children;
    $scope.averageGrowthRates += "<div class='cr_profile_ownership module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+ownership[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+ownership[1].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+ownership[2].innerHTML+"</div></div>";
  }).error(function(error){

    $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log(error.data);

  });
```

html

```
<ion-view view-title="Company">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
  </ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content id="comp">
  <ion-scroll>
    <h3 style="margin: 10px;">Company Info</h3>
    <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="companyInfo"></div>
    <h3 style="margin: 10px;">Description</h3>
    <div style="margin: 10px;font-size:20px;" ng-bind-html="companyDescription"></div>
    <div style="margin: 10px;color:#AAAFFF;font-size:40px;" ng-bind-html="keyPeople"></div>s   
    <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="averageGrowthRates"></div>
    <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="ownership"></div>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**UPDATED:**
With the current answers by @Manzurul and @Varun Sukheja.

1. The font size and color inside red box I draw ,both do not take effect
2. font size of table below the red box do not take effect, only color changed.

Thus, I am curious why the font size inside the red box unable to changed? More important how to changed it.

The picture is using

```
.controller("companyOwnershipCtrl",function($scope,$http,$ionicLoading,$state,$cashDataFactory){

$scope.companyDescriptionStyle = {"color": "blue", "font-size": "40px"};
```

in angularjs and `<div style="margin: 10px;font-size:20px;" ng-bind-html="companyDescription" ng-style="companyDescriptionStyle"></div>` in html, but you can notice the font size is same as the above.

[image]

The html code that scrapped from this link http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/U11/company-people

```
<div class="cr_profile_people module"> <div class="mod_headerBox"> <h3>Key People <span class="hdr_co_name">United Overseas Bank Ltd.</span></h3> </div> <div class="cr_data cr_board"> <h4>Board of Directors</h4> <table class="cr_dataTable cr_board_table"> <tbody> <tr> <th>Name/Title</th> <th>Current Board Membership</th> </tr> </tbody> </table> <div class="scrollBox"> <table class="cr_dataTable cr_board_table"> <tbody> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86291589">Ee Cheong Wee</a>, <span class="data_meta">63</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Deputy Chairman &amp; Chief Executive Officer</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">PT Bank UOB Indonesia, Visa International Senior Client Council, United Overseas Bank Ltd., Singapore-China Foundation Ltd., Far Eastern Bank Ltd., United Overseas Insurance Ltd., United Overseas Bank (Thai) Public Co. Ltd., United Overseas Bank (Malaysia) Bhd., The Institute of Banking &amp; Finance, United Overseas Bank (China) Ltd., Wee Foundation, United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore)</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/16055509">Michael Lien</a>, <span class="data_meta"></span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore)</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/104206">Cho Yaw Wee</a>, <span class="data_meta">88</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Chairman-Emeritus</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore)</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/16489539">Fu Hua Hsieh</a>, <span class="data_meta">66</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Chairman</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore)</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86320739">Khirn Hai Yeo</a>, <span class="data_meta">55</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore)</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/154674047">Kan Seng Wong</a>, <span class="data_meta">71</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore)</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/13470908">Alexander Charles Hungate</a>, <span class="data_meta">51</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore)</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/98308786">Hwee Hua Lim</a>, <span class="data_meta">57</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore), BW Group Ltd., Jardine Cycle &amp; Carriage Ltd., Stewardship &amp; Corporate Governance Centre Pte Ltd., PAP Community Foundation, Stewardship Asia Centre Pte Ltd.</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/104667">Cher Siang Koh</a>, <span class="data_meta">70</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">Singapore Housing &amp; Development Board, United Overseas Bank Ltd., CapitaLand Ltd., United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore), Thye Hua Kwan Moral Charities Ltd., Mechanobiology Institute, Singapore Golf Association, Singapore Cooperation Enterprise, CapitaLand Hope Foundation, Singapore Deposit Insurance Corp., Singapore Island Country Club</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/114522422">Yew Huat Ong</a>, <span class="data_meta">60</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore)</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86318967">Jue Hiang Cheng</a>, <span class="data_meta">62</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">SPH MediaBoxOffice Pte Ltd., SPH Interactive Pte Ltd., FEO Hospitality Trust Management Pte Ltd., Far East Hospitality Trust, FEO Hospitality Asset Management Pte Ltd., SPH Interactive International Pte Ltd., Singapore Institute of Directors, 701Search Pte Ltd., Ntuc Fairprice Foundation Ltd., Ashoka Innovators for the Public (Singapore) Ltd., United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore), Council For Third Age Ltd., Integrated Information Systems, Inc., Aescapulus Holdings Pte Ltd., Singapore Health Services Pte Ltd., Integrated Health Information Systems Pte Ltd., SymAsia Foundation Ltd., Asia Philantrophic Ventures Pte Ltd., Asia Philanthropic Ventures Pte Ltd., Caritas Humanitarian Aid &amp; Relief Initiatives, Singapore</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span class="data_data"> <a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/41491049">Franklin Leo Lavin</a>, <span class="data_meta">58</span> </span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </td> <td> <span class="data_lbl">Far Eastern Bank Ltd., Globe Specialty Metals, Inc., CONSISTEL (Singapore) Pte Ltd., United Overseas Bank Ltd. (Singapore), United Overseas Bank Ltd., Export Now, Inc.</span> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </div> <div class="bottomStrap_more"> <a href="#" id class="moreLink loadMoreLink">expand</a> </div> </div> <div class="cr_data cr_all_executives"> <h4>All Executives</h4> <div class="scrollBox"> <ul class="cr_data_collection cr_all_executives"> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86291589">Ee Cheong Wee</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Deputy Chairman &amp; Chief Executive Officer</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86291593">Wai Cheng Hwee</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Head-Group Technology &amp; Operations</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86291587">Wai Fai Lee</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Chief Financial Officer</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/4815192">Victor Ngo</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Head-Group Compliance</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/122181365">See-Ming Ip Yeung</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Managing Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/122099381">Chin Voon-Fat</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Head-Group Wholesale Banking</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/120136914">Kok Seong Chan</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Group Chief Risk Officer</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/115461061">Wah Yan Wong</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Head-Group Strategy &amp; International Management</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/160726">Terence Ong</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Head-Global Markets &amp; Investment Management</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86328526">Chin Yong Lee</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Head-Group Retail</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/16055509">Michael Lien</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/104206">Cho Yaw Wee</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Chairman-Emeritus</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/152463410">Carrie Ann Mathews</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Head-Group Strategic Communications</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/120300850">Shih Tung Lin</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Investor Relations Contact</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/95901534">Mei Leng Wong</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Head-Group Human Resources</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/138452461">Ming Kuang Sia</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Co-Secretary</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/151489730">Kwee Soik Sim</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Co-Secretary</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/16489539">Fu Hua Hsieh</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Chairman</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86320739">Khirn Hai Yeo</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/154674047">Kan Seng Wong</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/13470908">Alexander Charles Hungate</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/98308786">Hwee Hua Lim</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/104667">Cher Siang Koh</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/114522422">Yew Huat Ong</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/86318967">Jue Hiang Cheng</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> <li> <div class="cr_data_field"> <span class="data_data"><a href="http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/XSES/U11/company-people/executive-profile/41491049">Franklin Leo Lavin</a></span> <span class="data_lbl">Independent Non-Executive Director</span> </div> </li> </ul> </div> <div class="bottomStrap_more"> <a href="#" id class="moreLink loadMoreLink">expand</a> </div> </div> </div> </div> <!--data-module-name="quotes.module.companypeople.Module"--> <div intent in-at8units-append="#at8uTarget" in-at12units-append="#at12uTarget" in-at16units-append="#at12uTarget"> <div data-module-id="12" data-module-name="quotes.module.ads.responsiveAd" data-module-zone="ads" class="zonedModule"> <div class="boxadWrapper module" id="main-quotes-ad"> <span class="adTitle">Advertisement</span> <div class="quotes-ad-wrap" id="AD_G" data-ad-options="{&quot;adId&quot;:&quot;AD_G&quot;,&quot;adUnitPath&quot;:&quot;/2/asia.wsj.com/quotes_front&quot;,&quot;adSize&quot;:[[300,250],[300,1050]],&quot;adSizeMap&quot;:null,&quot;autoRefresh&quot;:false,&quot;adTargeting&quot;:{&quot;metazone&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;msrc&quot;:null,&quot;circ&quot;:&quot;nonsub&quot;,&quot;sym&quot;:&quot;U11&quot;,&quot;p39&quot;:null}}" data-tracking="asia.wsj.com/quotes_front" data-cb-ad-id="TopRectangle"> </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: For font-size, try setting it to "font-size: 20px", and for color, use syntax like "color: red".

Comment: In html or angularjs? `<div style="margin: 10px;font-size:20px;"ng-bind-html="keyPeople"></div>`?

Comment: Yup that should change the font size.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. That is why I don't understand why. As you can see from the picture, It contains title and table. Both font sizes does not change

Comment: Try with `!important` like this: `<div style="margin: 10px;font-size:20px !important;"ng-bind-html="keyPeople"></div>`

Comment: It is still the same. Possible need to change in angularjs?

Comment: Strange. You should probably post more code in the question. Without it, it is hard to know what might be going wrong. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NisargShah I have updated the full code. Please take a  look

Comment: You should consider providing a live example of the problem you are facing (e.g. a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [pen](https://codepen.io/)). Not only will help you to identify the issue yourself, but will also attract more answers.

Comment: It seems like inline style is being ignored when used with `ng-bind-html`? Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616212/angularjs-ignores-inline-style)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a CSS only solution to your problem

```
.cr_profile_people.module > .mod_headerBox > h3 {
    font-size: 10px!important;
}

.cr_profile_people.module .cr_dataTable.cr_board_table > tbody > tr > th {
    font-size: 40px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look I have used your all the ionic html code and also kept the h3 tags. And the ng-style is working fine.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  /*$http.get("http://manzurul.atwebpages.com")
  .success(function(response){ 
    console.log('workingsdfsdf');
    
  }).error(function(error){
 
    if(!error) {
        $scope.name = "No data found"
        $scope.companyDescriptionStyle = {"color": "red","font-size":"40px"}
    }
  });*/
  $scope.companyDescriptionStyle = {
    "color": "blue",
    "font-size": "40px"
  };
  $scope.name = 'World';
  //Company Info
  var companyInfo1 = null;
  var companyInfo2 = null;

  $scope.companyInfo = null;
  $scope.companyInfo += "";

  //Description
  var description1 = "";
  $scope.companyDescription = "<p></p>";


  //Key People
  var keyPeople1 = "";
  $scope.keyPeople = "";

  //Average Growth Rates
  var growth = "";
  var growth1 = "";
  $scope.averageGrowthRates = "";
  $scope.averageGrowthRates += "";

  //ownership
  var ownership = "";
  $scope.averageGrowthRates += "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-style="nameStyle">Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <ion-view view-title="Company">
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <ion-content id="comp">
        <ion-scroll>
          <h3 ng-style="companyDescriptionStyle">Company Info</h3>
          <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="companyInfo"></div>
          <h3 ng-style="companyDescriptionStyle">Description</h3>
          <div style="margin: 10px;font-size:20px;" ng-bind-html="companyDescription"></div>
          <div style="margin: 10px;color:#AAAFFF;font-size:40px;" ng-bind-html="keyPeople"></div>
          <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="averageGrowthRates"></div>
          <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="ownership"></div>
        </ion-scroll>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The key is `style="margin: 10px;font-size:20px;" ` is not work to enlarge the font. As point out above comments

Comment: This will not work through style property. This needs to be bind in
   $scope.companyDescriptionStyle = {"color": "red", "font-size": "20px"};
For more see the above plunker I have updated.

Comment: More over I need to clarify that if any css property does not have definition in angular class then you have use that property inside double quotation.

Comment: Strange enough, the font size does not take effect. Please refer my updates above. Is the direction to solve the problem is not right? I curious why the words in the red box, unable to change

Comment: @bkcollection I have seen your implementation. The answer is you cant do this by inline style, you have bind the style in angular way and then it will work.

Comment: May I know how to bind the style? Can you explain or show it in answer?

Comment: @bkcollection Saw your question update. If you already have $scope.companyDescriptionStyle then you need to add ng-style where you want to apply the style, like for company description

<div ng-style="companyDescriptionStyle" ng-bind-html="companyDescription" ></div>

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: I have did as you shown. I add `$scope.companyDescriptionStyle ` and also `<div ng-style="companyDescriptionStyle" ng-bind-html="companyDescription" ></div>`. Sorry that I forget to add it when I edited my post

Comment: If it still does not work, could you please make a plunker with your code so we can look. Also in your code in the question I dont see this $scope.companyDescriptionStyle = {"color": "blue", "font-size": "40px"}; Where did you put this?

Comment: I have edited the post again  `$scope.companyDescriptionStyle = {"color": "blue", "font-size": "40px"}; ` was added in controller as shown above. Sorry, I try to create a plunker that work before I post the questions but failed. The code unable to scrap the page in plunker. Really sorry about that

Comment: Did you see this plunker where I have used the same approach and its working... https://plnkr.co/edit/CjcJOi0WrxtKXJdG2fOw?p=preview

Comment: By the way which version of angular you are using?

Comment: Yes, I did. The difference is the plunker is changing using html while I am using `ng-bind-html`. Also, I scrap from webpage. I believe that is the difference. I am using ionic 1, should be angular 1.5

Comment: No I think that is not the problem. Problem is somewhere else. See this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/tgte2ygO9n3NJ4K8lkW3?p=preview Where I have used your code and the ng-style is working perfectly. Since ajax request is failed due cross origin, you can see the code in error section where it is working. It is not working because it is not getting into the success function.

Comment: The font size and colors did not take effect due to the <h3> tag in the html code that I want to scrap. Please refer the updated post above. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you keep saying that where in the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/tgte2ygO9n3NJ4K8lkW3 I showed you that the ng-style is working on h3 tag too? Its the problem that your data source does not return any data, so http request automatically go into .error(){} block. It will work well on the scrapped content too if your ajax request is success.

Comment: Now see the answer I have updated the answer and added snipet of code which is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class direcitve to apply your class

see the usage here : [ng-class](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-class.asp)
You can define class in your css file

```
    . companyDescriptionStyle {"color":"blue"};
```

No you can use this class in ng-class

```
    <div style="margin: 10px;font-size:20px;" ng-bind-html="companyDescription" ng-class="companyDescriptionStyle"></div>
```

Comment: same issues, the font-size:20px is not taking effect to enlarge the font